# . I need to average the values stored in multiple rows in an excel spread sheet, but exclude any empty rows

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

It's basically all in the title. I need to add up the values of all the cells in the rows, then average those totals across 30 rows, but my running average needs to exclude the rows that don't have any values added yet. The problem is really trying to keep the formula concise so that I'm not typing all day. Anybody have any suggestions?

[Here you can see what I'm talking about. It's not all that complicated but my words sometimes fail me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl4lO.png)

Comment: only 18 rows in your screen shot, not 30.  Your cell and row reference numbers are missing so assumptions to addresses will need to be made.  Looks like body weight is a split cell...are all day columns merged cells?  What do you mean by a "Running" average

Answer (score 0):

The average formula does ignore blanks.

Example put 1 in A1 and A3

In B1 put `=AVERAGE(A1:A3)`

It says 1 if it counted blanks it would say 0.6666666